# Writing a sparkdataframe to a .csv file in S3 and choose a name in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and a i am going to write it an a .csv file in S3
i use the following code:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("dbfs:/mnt/mount1/2016//product_profit_weekly",mode='overwrite',header=True)
```

it puts a .csv file in product_profit_weekly folder , at the moment .csv file has a weired name in S3 , is it possible to choose a file name when i am going to write it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All spark dataframe writers (df.write.___) don't write to a single file, but write one chunk per partition.  I imagine what you get is a directory called

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("dbfs:/mnt/mount1/2016//product_profit_weekly
```

and one file inside called

```
part-00000
```

In this case, you are doing something that could be quite inefficient and not very "sparky" -- you are coalescing all dataframe partitions to one, meaning that your task isn't actually executed in parallel!

Here's a different model.  To take advantage of all spark parallelization, which means DON'T coalesce, and write in parallel to some directory.

If you have 100 partitions, you will get:

```
part-00000
part-00001
...
part-00099
```

If you need everything in one flat file, write a little function to merge it after the fact.  You could either do this in scala, or in bash with:

```
cat ${dir}.part-* > $flatFilePath
```

Comment: Ok, but what if i have one file and i want to define a name for it for example: report.csv and then write it?

Comment: @zero323 i would appreciate your help

Comment: If you are really interested in one file, you might want to do something like "collect" the dataframe first and use the standard java file writers.  These will produce a flat file wherever you like -- the spark parallel writers don't look like what you want.

Comment: @sanaz - did you get a solution for this problem? I am facing the exact same thing at the moment..

Comment: if you want 1 file, you can also call `coalesce(1)` on your data frame before the write. Beware that this will try to shuffle all the data to one executioner and 1 partition, so if the data is very large, this can cause OOM errors.